# Lua patterns become confused with unusual characters

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

So, I tried to separate text in Lua. The following code perfectly separates a string with "§§§" as a separator.

```
    local t={}
    for str in string.gmatch(inputstr, "([^§§§]+)") do
            table.insert(t, str)
    end
```

So when I set `inputstr="One§§§Two§§§Three"` t comes out as `{One, Two, Three}`

But then I needed to separate a text with a ` in it. If I set `inputstr="One§§§Two´Three"` t comes out as {`One, Two, �Three}`.

I don't mind the unknown character symbol, but it also separates the string there.
I also tried some other uncommon symbols, for example, emojis have the same problem.

Anyone had the same problem or knows a solution for this?

Comment: This is because `§ (U+00A7)` is `C2,A7` and many other symbols have `C2` too, for example, your quote `´ (U+00B4)` is `C2,B4`.  So, it is `C2` who is the separator.  The solution is `for str in inputstr:gsub("§§§", "\0"):gmatch("%Z+") do`

Comment: This works very well, thanks. The "§§§" is just a separator I chose. Even though it works now, can you recommend a "safer" separator in terms of working with, that doesn't appear that often in normal text.

Comment: Even if you did choose a one-byte character, note that `[^XXX]` is the same as `[^X]`, since the brackets form a set of characters.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Josh Thanks for cleaning up my code